# How does the GZip algorithm work?

Tags: gzip

How does the GZip file compression algorithm work? If anyone has any documentation on this, I'd like to read it.

Comment: A short description of how GZIP works:

[http://stackoverflow.com/a/19799494/2066118][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19799494/2066118

Comment: A short description of how the algorithm works:

[http://stackoverflow.com/a/19799494/2066118][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19799494/2066118

Answer (score 27):

If you're still looking for a more detailed overview, I've written up a description of the gzip deflate process, along with source code, at: http://www.infinitepartitions.com/art001.html

Answer (score 9):

[Compression algorithm (deflate)](http://www.gzip.org/algorithm.txt)

[Gzip User's Manual](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gzip/gzip_toc.html)

Also visit

**[The gZip home page.](http://www.gzip.org/)**

Comment: The first two links are broken